# Creating entries with image attachements within posts and managing them in a list

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox

I need help with choosing a suitable meta box or other means for listing, adding and sorting entries, relevant to the containing post. For each entry it should be possible to attach a set of images, for example by using an WP "Add Media" button. The images should be attached to the entries and not to the containing post. It should also be possible to edit and delete entries.

I've thought of having these entries as regular posts of some type/category and I think that could work, but they're actually only relevant to the containing post and my thinking is that it could be sensible to avoid it. What do you think?

So, in other words I have two problems:

1. How to create a kind of "mini post" with image attachments.
2. How to create an interface to manage them inside the containing post admin page.

Does anyone have suggestions on how this could be approached or on any plugin that could be useful for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with WPAlchemy and its function [have_fields_and_multi()](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#have_fields_and_multi). It allows for adding an arbitrary number of sections (by means of an 'Add New' button), called groups, that can contain all the metadata I needed, including links to images which can be added using the Add Media dialog which was made easily accessible by WPAlchemy. All metadata is then saved and linked to that post. WPAlchemy is pretty easy to use once understood. I found the documentation too brief in parts. In any case I found it makes designing posting interfaces much easier.

As I understand it groups can not yet be nested but this could come in a future update.